# How to download the photos to desktop folder from url retrieve from python?

Tags: html, image, download

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = "https://www.opi.com/shop-products/nail-polish-powders/nail-lacquer"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

for img in soup.select('#all_nail_lacquer [typeof="foaf:Image"][data-src]'):
    print(img['data-src'].replace('shelf_image', 'photos')) # <-- this is URL to hi-res image
    print('-' * 80)
```

I got this program to gather all the links associated with the products photo. Now, I want to be able to automatically open each link and save the photo to a specific folder. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

For downloading images, you can use the urllib module.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

folder = "C:/tmp/"

theurl = "https://www.opi.com/shop-products/nail-polish-powders/nail-lacquer"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

for img in soup.select('#all_nail_lacquer [typeof="foaf:Image"][data-src]'):
    picurl = img['data-src'].replace('shelf_image', 'photos')
    print(picurl) # <-- this is URL to hi-res image
    print('-' * 80)
    f1 = picurl.split('/')[-1] # living-on-the-bula-vard-nlf81-nail-lacquer-22006698181_12_0_0_0.jpg?itok=6RDDxV8f
    f2 = f1.split('?')[0]  # living-on-the-bula-vard-nlf81-nail-lacquer-22006698181_12_0_0_0.jpg
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(picurl, folder + f2)
```